# increasing nav and li

Tags: html, css

I have problem with nav. When i hover this all are increasing, but i dont know why. But before when i clear line in ol > li width: 150px; all is ok, but i need content and 30padding left and right and i dont know why is doing like that. When you have more que write

```
<!--

<nav>

            <ol>

                <li><a href="#">Example</a>

                    <ul>

                        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#">Example</a>

                    <ul>

                        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </li>

                <li><a href="#">Example</a>

                    <ul>

                        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </li>

                <li><a href="#">Example</a>

                    <ul>

                        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </li>

                <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>


                    <li><a href="#">Example</a>

                    <ul>

                        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>

                    </ul> 

                </li>

            </ol>

    </nav>

-->
```

content content content content content content

```
/*

nav
{ 
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fdd031;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #333;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

ol
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 35px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 200%;
    display: inline-block;
}

ol a
{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

ol > li
{
    float: left;
    padding: 0 30px;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFDF00;
}

ol > li:first-child
{
    border-left: 1px solid #FFDF00;
}

ol > li > ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 0 30px;
}

ol > li > ul > li
{
    background-color: #fdd031;
    padding: 0 8px;
    z-index: 1000;
    border-top: 1px dashed #FFDF00;
}

ol > li:hover > a
{
    color: #FFF;
    transition: 400ms;
}

ol > li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
}

ol > li > ul > li:hover > a
{
    color: #FFF;
    transition: 400ms;
}

*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you got confused with padding and you added it multiple times
If you remove padding from lists(ul) and list elements(li)
and just add it padding in your link elements(a) the problem is solved

```
ol a {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding: 0 30px; /* add this */
}

ol > li {
float: left;
/* padding: 0 30px;  REMOVE*/
margin: 0;
border-right: 1px solid #FFDF00;}

ol > li > ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
display: none;
font-size: 15px;
text-align: justify;
/* padding: 0 30px; REMOVE*/
}

ol > li > ul > li{
background-color: #fdd031;
/* padding: 0 8px; REMOVE*/
z-index: 1000;
border-top: 1px dashed #FFDF00;
}
```

Working Demo: https://codepen.io/stellageo/pen/MWaZLmx